# how to make debian packages for ros fuerte or groovy

Tags: ros, catkin, rosdeb, packages, debian

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems to be a very confusing matter. There exists ros_release, with rosdeb , also there is a catkin-deb and bloom, and think I have seen different repositories with this tools.

The question is simple: How to make a debian package out of a ros package or stack in fuerte and how it is done in groovy.

I want to make my own debian repository by compiling all the packages from ros again but in debian (and maybe fixing in the way whatever is necessary). I have managed to build ros-fuerte-catkin ros-fuerte-rospack ros-fuerte-ros vcstools and others, but once I want something like rviz (or visualization stack), then I don't know where to look for.

I also have seen this: github . com/ros/rosdistro/blob/master/releases/fuerte.yaml which has a list that I can almost compile completely to debian, but still just basic ros stuff, and not the useful packages.

I have seen also instructions on how to add ros packages to a buildfarm which I guess is in willowgarage to generate for me the debian package, but I want to generate my own packages, also for debian sid and not for ubuntu.

I would expect for this sort of thing also some kind of tool to build all packages and its dependecies recursively automaticaly.

Any help of how to do this would be awesome.

All the best,
Federico.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/57713/how-to-make-debian-packages-for-ros-fuerte-or-groovy/) by [memeruiz](https://answers.ros.org/users/4395/memeruiz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2013-03-10

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The you can find the [release system](http://www.ros.org/wiki/release) documented on the wiki.  Depending on which version you are releasing for you will get different tools.

Compiling all these packages into debians takes quite an large effort and infrastructure.  There's an ongoing effort to make this easier.  You can see the ongoing discussion in the [REP 137](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/rep/pull/27) discussion.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-03-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2